# Remove items and at some time later add those removed items back into List at the same indexes

Tags: java, collections

I have a scenario where I need to remove some items from a List and then later at sometime I need to add those removed items back to the List on same indexes from where those were removed...

The List can contain hundreds of items.... I am thinking that when removing items, store those removed item in Map, with index as key and item as value... The removed items Map will help me when adding back these removed items back to the List as I will have the indexes as keys in the Map so that I can restore them on the same indexes in the List.. I need to check with you guys that if this approach is good, and if not what other alternative can be applied...

Comment: Wouldn't a filter be more appropriate?

Comment: If you are using a List, and indices are important for your logic, remember that removing an item will change the indices of the remaining items. As mentioned, filters could work better for you, otherwise, why don't you try an array?

Comment: What is your current code approach?

Comment: If indices are reserved for a particular item, why can't we use a map from the beginning. That way even if you remove an item, the indices(key) will still be reserved. Unlike in a list when you remove an item, the list reshuffles and assigns this index to a new item.